# Internet Explorer CSS rotation wobble

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, css-animations, css-transforms

I have an SVG element with a circle inside it. The SVG is being rotated infinitely using a keyframe animation:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0%       { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100%     { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

svg{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  animation: rotate 2.9s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

My issue is that, on Internet Explorer 11, the rotation seems to wobble slightly as it is rotating (all other browsers behave as expected). Try focusing on the top or left edges of the black box.

**Is there any way I can avoid this?**

[Here's a fiddle with the test scenario.](https://jsfiddle.net/dhkn7ksr/7/)

And below is a gif that showcases it as well:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, here's how I managed to work around this: The SVG's `transform-origin` should be set to the circle's radius (in this case 250px) **in all dimensions**(x, y and z).

```
svg{
  /* other styles go here */
  transform-origin: 250px 250px 250px;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work for me on IE or Edge. See gif of the result: http://i.imgur.com/nVZi57X.gifv and JsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ananaszjoe/4h025hjn/